# using angularjs and JIC to upload file to S3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas, amazon-s3

I have angular upload to S3 working, but I would like to compress (or shrink) the image file down to height 250 px. Using angular upload:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        $scope.files = $files;
            $scope.upload = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                var file = $files[i];
                console.log('file: ' + JSON.stringify(file));
                file.progress = parseInt(0);
```

....

and then process with the upload. This works great... except for the size issue. So, I ended up trying to use a library called JIC (https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C) to handle the compression. The result of my console.log(file) is:

```
file: {"webkitRelativePath":"","lastModifiedDate":"2014-04-25T19:35:22.000Z","name":"pooltable.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":1922990}
```

I try passing this file to compress and then proceed to upload to S3, but it does not work:

```
var file = compress($files[i], 50, $files[i].type);
```

Here is the compress code from JIC which I modified to fit my heigh requirement:

```
var compress = function(source_img_obj, quality, output_format){

        var mime_type = "image/jpeg";
        if(output_format != undefined && output_format == "png"){
            mime_type = "image/png";
        }
        var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ratio = 250 / source_img_obj.naturalHeight;
        cvs.width = ratio * source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
        cvs.height = 250;
        var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
        var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, ratio/100);
        var result_image_obj = new Image();
        result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
        return result_image_obj;
    };
```

The problem here is that my source_img_obj doesn't come from HTML, it comes from the user uploading the image from their local machine so it does not have a src property and I get this error:

```
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

I don't actually want to draw the images into my html file, I just want to shrink them and upload them directly to the server.

Comment: [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) does all of this for you (scaling and upload to s3) all client side.

Comment: http://fineuploader.com/faq

Comment: Which angular upload you are using?

Comment: There's two: 1. https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload 2. https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload